# Eliminar o cambiar texto en switch

Tags: xaml, maui

Estoy tratando de cambiar o eliminar el texto de un switch button en MAUI pero ni en [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/switch), ni en otros lugares encuentro nada al respecto.

El elemento es sencillo:

```
 <Switch x:Name="styleSwitch"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         Scale="1.3"/>
```

En el estilo cuento con:

```
<Style TargetType="Switch">
        <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="On">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Secondary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray400}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Pero no encuentro ninguna propiedad para eliminar o poder cambiar esto:

[image: Desactivado]

[image: Activado]

¿Cómo puedo eliminar o cambiar ese texto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según parece, es un bug que se encuentra actualmente abierto como se puede ver en [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6177), solo se tiene constancia que ocurre en Windows, mientras que en dispositivos android, el funcionamiento es correcto.